# What conditions must we satisfy to apply methods like change of variables in ODE's?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

When we have the ODE $\frac{dx}{dt}+x+f(t)=0$
We can use the fact that $\frac{d(xe^t)}{dt}=\frac{dx}{dt}e^t+xe^t$ to rewrite the ODE as $\frac{d(xe^t )}{dt}+e^tf(t)=0$. This allows us to easily solve the equation, and then solve for $x(t)$.

**However, I am wondering: are there some kind of "hidden assumptions" that we are making when applying this kind of rule?** Are we using the assumption that $e^t$ is a strictly positive monotonically increasing function, or something like that?

The same question can be asked of methods like substituting $t= ln(\tau)$, in order to get $\frac{dx(ln(\tau))}{d\tau}$

**When can we apply this rule, and other similar rules? More importantly, what is the proof that it will result in a correct answer?**

---

**EDIT: In the hope of reviving this question:**

say we have the bernoulli equation:  $\frac{dx}{dt}+f(t)x+g(t)x^3$
We can solve this by setting $z(t)=x^2$, taking the derivative, and substituting in the equation. This gives
$\frac{1}{2}\frac{dz}{dt}+f(t)+g(t)z$

However, given that $z(t)$ is not a monotonic function of $x$, doesn't that cause problems when trying to recalculate $x$?

Comment: It seems to me that you only require that $e^t$ is non-zero.  Once you solve the ODE for $x(t)e^t$ then you must divide by $e^t$ to recover your original function $x(t)$. In order for this to be well defined for all $t$ of course you must have $e^t\neq 0$ for all $t$.

Comment: The rule is not "hidden". We have a linear inhomogenous ODE. The standard procedure can be found here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_differential_equation

Comment: I have edited another example.